# /bin/sh: extract_descriptors_cli: command not found

Tags: python, scons, sift

I am running the source code of Local Naive Bayer Nearest Neighbor form this site :

https://github.com/sanchom/sjm

i extract SIFT descriptor of the dataset Caltech 101 by running:

```
python extract_caltech.py --dataset_path /users/phongnguyen/desktop/101_ObjectCategories --process_limit 3 --sift_normalization_threshold 2.0 --sift_discard_unnormalized --sift_grid_type FIXED_3X3 --sift_first_level_smoothing 0.66 --sift_fast --sift_multiscale  --features_directory /users/phongnguyen/desktop/feature
```

Ad suggested on the site,

i got this error:

```
/bin/sh: extract_descriptors_cli: command not found
```

and it displays thousands of the same line above.

What wrong with the bug above, am i missing any binary file?

Answer (score 0):

You probably skipped one or more steps from the BUILDING section of the README.md, specifically

> you need to run `scons` to compile the binaries and then "`scons install BIN_PREFIX=[directory]` to install them in `[directory]`."

Comment: I run 'scons' but it generates some error on linking like: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: const*, int const&, int const&) in codebook_test.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
scons: *** [codebooks/codebook_test] Error 1. So i run 'scons /path/to/dependencies/directory' instead.

Comment: You need to fix the error. I don't see how the second `scons` invocation would help.

Comment: I still get problem with 'scone'. Will reply back if something changed. Thanks!

Comment: Create a new question and post the exact error message there plus the steps to reproduce it (i.e. download, unpack, cd, ...)

Comment: i posted a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23561253/unknown-command-line-flag-logtostderr @Aaron Digulla please help me.