# unknown command line flag 'logtostderr'

Tags: python, sift, gflags, glog

I am running this SIFT program at this site: https://github.com/sanchom/sjm

All the stuffs go well until I run my program:

```
$ python extract_caltech.py --dataset_path=[path_to_your_101_Categories_directory] \
--process_limit [num_processes_to_spawn] --sift_normalization_threshold 2.0 -- sift_discard_unnormalized \
--sift_grid_type FIXED_3X3 --sift_first_level_smoothing 0.66 --sift_fast --sift_multiscale \
--features_directory [path_for_extracted_features]
```

In the output, I see this line thousands of times:

```
ERROR: unknown command line flag 'logtostderr'
```

I have checked for some solutions as suggested here:

https://code.google.com/p/google-glog/issues/detail?id=17&q=glog%20gflagsBut

What I did is to add `GLOG_logtostderr=1` before I run my program:

```
GLOG_logtostderr=1 ./my_application
```

But it did not work our for me.

As far as I know, its the problem related to linking between Gflags and Glog. But i haven't got any ideas on how to solve it yet. Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`$GLOG_logtostderr=1` isn't doing what you expect. `$name` means "replace this with the value of the environment variable `name`". But you want to define a new variable. Use this instead:

```
GLOG_logtostderr=1 ./my_application
```

(i.e. omit the `$`).

Comment: Yep, i did type GLOG_logtostderr=1 ./my_application But it did not work out.

Comment: Please stop saying "does not work." This doesn't allow anyone in the world to help you. Always include the exact error message, log output or anything that might allow someone to spot the problem.

Comment: Sorry, after i run: GlOG_logtostderr=1 ./my_application. Then i got : {'sift_grid_type': 'FIXED_3X3', 'features_directory': '/users/phongnguyen/desktop/features', 'sift_normalization_threshold': 2.0, 'sift_discard_unnormalized': True, 'sift_multiscale': True, 'sift_fast': True, 'sift_minimum_radius': 0, 'sift_smoothed': True, 'process_limit': 3, 'sift_first_level_smoothing': 0.66, 'dataset_path': '/users/phongnguyen/downloads/101_ObjectCategories'}
 ERROR: unknown command line flag 'logtostderr' ERROR: unknown command line flag 'logtostderr'ERROR: unknown command line flag 'logtostderr'.....

Comment: there are thousands of lines: ERROR: unknown command line flag 'logtostderr'following.

Comment: You write `GlOG_`, `GFLOG_` and `GLOG_`. I assume those are just typos when you wrote this question?

Comment: Have a you gflags and glog installed or only SIFT?

Comment: Yes, i did install both gflags and glog via Macport

Comment: When you run `scons` to build the software, do you see that it finds those libraries?

Comment: Yes, i do see both of it.

Comment: I just run scons again and this time it just shows : Phongs-MacBook-Pro:sjm phongnguyen$ scons
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
scons: `.' is up to date.
scons: done building targets.

Comment: `scons` has rules to find out when nothing in a project changed and then skips the build. Run `scons clean` to delete all the generated files.

Comment: Something else I just noticed. What's this `./my_application`?

Comment: Its the script i run: python extract_caltech.py --dataset_path=[path_to_your_101_Categories_directory] \
--process_limit [num_processes_to_spawn] --sift_normalization_threshold 2.0 -- sift_discard_unnormalized \
--sift_grid_type FIXED_3X3 --sift_first_level_smoothing 0.66 --sift_fast --sift_multiscale \
--features_directory [path_for_extracted_features]

Comment: I run 'scons --clean' to delete all the generated files. And i run scons again. I got some lines  g++ -o codebooks/codebook_cli codebooks/codebook_cli.o -L. -Lsift -Lutil -Lcodebooks -Lspatial_pyramid -Lnaive_bayes_nearest_neighbor -**lglog** -**lgflags** -lsift_lib -lboost_system-mt -lboost_filesystem-mt -lcodebooks_lib -lprotoc -lflann -lpthread -lprotobuf.  Does the lglog and lgflags in bold indicates that Scons finds out those two libraries?

Comment: Re `./my_application`: So you actually run `GLOG_logtostderr=1 python ...`?

Comment: Re -lglog -lgflags: Yes. You should be able to see them in the output of `ldd codebooks/codebook_cli`, too.

Comment: Can you make sure that the version of `glog` which you installed actually supports this flag? Also, I'm wondering what "unknown command line flag" means since I don't see this on the command line that you type. Can you look into `extract_caltech.py` to see if you can find `logtostderr` in there somewhere? If not, can you search the whole project for this string?

Comment: @PhongNguyen Look at [`caltech_util.py`](https://github.com/sanchom/sjm/blob/master/naive_bayes_nearest_neighbor/caltech_util.py). It explicitly includes `--logtostderr` in a command.

Comment: @PhongNguyen Also, `codebook_cli` is never called from `extract_caltech.py`, so don't think it is relevant. `extract_caltech.py` calls `extract_descriptors_cli`.

Comment: @AaronDigulla there is no **logtostderr** at all inside extract_caltech.py. I am searching for it at another files as well.

Comment: @AaronDigulla Yes i run GLOG_logtostderr=1 python .... And It shows the same error: unknown command line flag 'logtostderr' if i omit GLOG_logtostderr=1.

Comment: @Articuno Yes, i see 'logtostderr' inside Caltech_util.py. There are many more other stuffs besides:    codebooks/codebook_cli codebooks/codebook_cli.o ....such as: g++ -o naive_bayes_nearest_neighbor/experiment_3/experiment_3 naive_bayes_nearest_neighbor/experiment_3/experiment_3.o -L. -Lsift -Lutil -Lcodebooks -Lspatial_pyramid -Lnaive_bayes_nearest_neighbor -**lglog** -**lgflags** -lflann -lsift_lib -lboost_system-mt -lboost_filesystem-mt -lprotobuf -lpthread

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my problem. Its because IIRC macports' glog is not built with gflags but the python script sets --logtostderr. So just remove --logtostderr from the python script by running the script:

```
find . -name '*.py' -exec perl -i -p -e 's/--logtostderr//' {} \;
```

To find out if you're affected, run

```
ldd libglog.so
```

and check if libgflags is in the output.

The solution is suggested from this site:

https://code.google.com/p/google-glog/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=206

Comment: Macports glog now has a gflags dependency. It was added yesterday.

Comment: How can a user tell whether glog supports gflags?

Comment: @AaronDigulla You could do `ldd libglog.so` and check if libgflags is in the output.